# Trying to change color of transparent part in an image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hi I'm Trying to change color of transparent part of image.Please Refer the Image 
Actually i am using it as a background image in a grid is there any way to change color of only outer part of that image i.e transparent part and no effect should be applied on main part of image which is opaque.On Tap of "FwdBtn" image outer Transparent part of main Image should change.
Xaml

```
 <Grid.Background>

            <ImageBrush x:Name="imgbg" ImageSource="Assets/LearnColor/bg.png"
                        />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefHeaderPanel" Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefContentPanel" Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefFooterPanel" Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="Headerpanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image x:Name="prevBtn" 
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_previous_arrow.png"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
               Margin="0,33,-246,23"
               Tapped="BckImgChng" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="88" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
            <Image x:Name="FwdBtn"
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Button/btn_next_arrow.png"              
               Height="88"
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
               Margin="-152,0,250,-121"
               Tapped="FwdImgChng" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
            <Image x:Name="Header" 
            Source="Assets/LearnColor/Header/_0000_header_0.png" Width="440"
               RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"                 
               Margin="0,-39,-814,-62" HorizontalAlignment="Right"               
               >
                <Image.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="Blinkopr">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.9" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="Header"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>

                    </EventTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderName"
                Text="Yellow"
                       FontFamily="Font/BALLOON.TTF#BALLOON"
              RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"                 
               Margin="543,13,-273,7" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />

        </RelativePanel>
```

C# code

```
private void FwdImgChng(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (currentIndex == 11)
            //{ return; }
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex > 10)
            {
                currentIndex = 10;
                return;
            }

            Header.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Header/_0000_header_" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + currentIndex + "_0.png"));
            prevObjBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Button/prev" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            fwdObjBtn.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Button/next" + currentIndex + ".png"));
            HeaderName.Text = Headername[currentIndex];            
            objNameWritten.Text = objnamewritten[currentIndex];
            objNameWritten.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(HColorname[currentIndex]);
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Objectnamesmp3/C" + currentIndex + ".mp3");
            //mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;


        }
```

Image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your grid inside another control and set the background for that, you can use any control you like, for example I have used another grid here:

```
<Grid Background="#c0c0c0">
<!-- Your grid here-->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi I'm Trying same image like this as you mentioned <Grid x:Name="Mainbg">
        <Grid x:Name="2ndgrid">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="imgbg" ImageSource="Assets/bg.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Button x:Name="btn"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Tapped="btnTap"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>   C # code    private void btnTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Mainbg.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
        } but giving error any resolution

Comment: @Edmad it's working Actually i shouldn't give 2nd grid name  as "2ndgrid".it is not in correct format when i change the name it works..

Comment: @anuj Great. You can mark the answer if you want to help others see the result and upvote to make me happy :)